# Combining diacritic marks don't work in iCloud Pages?

Tags: icloud, pages, unicode

Here is what it looks like if I type an "e" followed by an acute accent combining character, in macOS Pages (and in most good text editing programs).

[image]

Here's what happens in iCloud Pages.

[image]

I sent something via the "submit feedback" menu item.

Are others seeing this? Is there a fix or workaround? It's too bad. This will force me to Google docs.

I need them for stress marks on Cyrillic characters, so I cannot use the standard Mac dead-key shortcuts.

Safari: 11.1.1. macOS 10.13.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug.  I think to add combining marks to Cyrillic characters you will have to use another app.

Answer (score 1):

You can press and hold the e key to get this é. Works on many letters. For example, press and hold the o key gives you this.

[image]

You can choose the accent  you want. Works in most apps including Pages.

Comment: That's nice to know but it doesn't help me when writing in Russian and putting stress marks on the Cyrillic characters. Eg, я люблю́ э́ту кни́гу.